# Remove radio button by default checked in zend

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

Hi guys I am trying to remove radio button by default checked in my application

AS I am new to zend I couldn't able to understand how to do that

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Get single selection action column for grid.
 * 
 * @return Bvb_Grid_Extra_Column
 */
protected function getSingleSelectionActionColumn()
{
    $column = new Bvb_Grid_Extra_Column();
    $selection = $this->getView()->render('_partial/selection-order.phtml');
    $column->position('left')->name('selection')->title('')->decorator($selection);

    return  $column;
}
```

View:selection-order.phtml

```
<span class="actions">
<input name="ticketId" id="ticketId-{{ticketId}}" type="radio" class="selectAll js-set-order-ticket" value="{{ticketId}}"/>
```

Can anyone help me how can I do that

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a form object? do you populate it?

Comment: yes i am populating it

Comment: can we see your form code? It looks like you have hard coded HTML for your form? Did you not use the Zend Form classes?

Comment: As it is a too big code thats why i didn't posted here. as it will connect too many pages that code was not in one single page.

Comment: don't you call something like $form->render() anywhere?

Comment: From my controller :  $this->view->ticketGridObject =  $ticketGridService->getGrid(Ticket_Service_Grid::GRID_TYPE_ORDERTICKETOVERVIEW, $params);

Comment: From view:     <?php
    if (!empty($this->ticketGridObject)) :
        echo $this->headScript();
        echo $this->ticketGridObject;
    else :
    ?>