# Depending on condition display select box in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi guys i am trying to display select box when there is no grid object. And if i have grid now it will not shown that select box..
But in my case i would like to show select box when grid object also there

Like below

[image]

Here is my view page code:

```
<div>
<?php
if (!empty($this->ticketGridObject)) :
    echo $this->headScript();
    echo $this->ticketGridObject;
else :
?>
<span class="order-ticket-source-text">
    <label><?php echo $this->translate('ticket_source_led_to_order');?> : </label>
</span>

<span class="order-ticket-source-select">
    <select id="ticketSource">
        <option value="">--<?php echo $this->translate('select') ?>--</option>
        <?php foreach ($this->ticketSources as $ticketSource) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ticketSource->source ;?>"><?php echo $ticketSource->source;?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
</span>
<span class="source-add-icon js-add-new-ticket">
    <img src="/themes/bas/icons/fatcow/16x16/add.png"/>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
 /**
 * Get order ticket details
 */
public function ticketDetailsAction()
{
    $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('orderId', 0);
    $contactId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('contactId', 0);
    $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
    $ticketService = new Tickets_Service_Ticket($bootstrap->getOptions());
    $userId = $this->getUserInfo()->getId();
    $params = array(
        'depotAndAffiliateIds' => array_keys($this->_affiliatedDepotMastersWithActiveDepot),
        'orderId' => $orderId,
        'contactId' => (int)$contactId,
        'user' => $userId,
    );
    $options = array(
        'language' => BAS_Shared_Model_Ticket::LANGUAGE_DEFAULT,
        'user' => $userId,
        'translate' => $bootstrap->getResource('translate'),
        'config' => $bootstrap->getResource('config'),
    );
    $ticketGridService = new Ticket_Service_Grid($ticketService, $options);
    if (0 < (int)$contactId) {
        $this->view->ticketGridObject =  $ticketGridService->getGrid(Ticket_Service_Grid::GRID_TYPE_ORDERTICKETOVERVIEW, $params);
    }
    if (empty($this->view->ticketGridObject)) {
        $where = array('depot_id in (?)' => array_keys($this->_affiliatedDepotMastersWithActiveDepot));
        $this->view->ticketSources = $ticketService->getTicketSourceList($where);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me
How can i do that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: No its not showing that select box

Comment: yes your condition is saying correct but its not showing any select box in my case..do i need to remove else condition no rite?

Comment: My requirement is for first time it will just show that select box.. after user selected option from select bx it will show grid only..but now i would like to display grid with select box too.

Comment: when you select something,page get refreshed or jQuery do the job?

Comment: jquery do the job page wont get refreshed

Comment: NO its not..now the code which i have sent is working like if grid was there there is no select box is displaying..as i  have else condition in view

Comment: if you want to show select-box every time then remove `if` condition.simple

Comment: you mean this line if (!empty($this->ticketGridObject)) : and else one ?

Comment: its working and one more condition here

Comment: yes. you are right. `one more condition here`-> what?

Comment: In my case for first time i dont need to show that message as or create a new one ? AS i shown in picture

that text has to show only when grid available only

Comment: hi if it is possible can you please check this question once..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892276/remove-radio-button-by-default-checked-in-zend